# Domain Driven Design - Singletons

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, domain-driven-design

It's a bad idea to create a singleton when we are using ddd?

I'm thinking of creating two of them, one for global settings (which are saved in the database) and the other for local settings (which are saved in the Windows Registry in my application windows forms).

If singletons in ddd is acceptable, where and when should I fill them with the stored values?

Comment: Do you have an example of use? What components needs to access these values? I'd usually solve the configuration problem at the composition root of my application. Only the root would have access to a configuration and environment which means you do not need the configuration to be globally reachable.

Comment: A singleton is an implementation detail, it has nothing to do with DDD.

Comment: "Settings" aren't usually part of the domain; they are typically an application concern.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason It depends on how you design your architecture. For example, some settings that might be who knows where could be configurable properties of some repository or service implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singletons implemented *as is* <sup>(1)</sup> aren't acceptable in DDD **based on your case**<sup>(2)</sup> and even in any other modern software development paradigm. Note that *DDD* is more than a software architectural paradigm, but when I say that *common singleton implementation isn't acceptable* I'm talking about *how to properly implement DDD in programming languages like C#*.

For example, the following code sample is a possible simple implementation of *singleton*:

```
// Very simple singleton using a static field initializer
public class SimpleSingleton
{
     private readonly static SimpleSingleton _instance = new SimpleSingleton();

     public SimpleSingleton Instance => _instance;
}
```

They're not *swappable*, and this means that you can't inject them using dependency injection<sup>(3)</sup>. That is, testing is harder to implement too (*you should understand that a system that can't be tested or it's hard to test is a very bad idea*).

What can be acceptable is using a dependency injection/inversion of control container that can define component implementations' life-style like Castle Windsor and others, which means that you can still use dependency injection and define that only a single instance will be created during the life of the application (*i.e. you get an instance where you get an injected component implementation, but once one is created by the internal component factory, this is the one that's being injected during one application life-cycle*).

At the end of the day, your system is designed to be agnostic about how component life-cycle works. It's defined by configuration. I would say that *object life management* is an *aspect* when your system is designed this way ([see this Wikipedia article to learn more about aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)).

Delegating component life management to an *aspect* and define what kind of life will have your components is a great advantage: your code can work in many hosting environments and on each of them your code can work differently by configuration.

Think about an ASP.NET WebAPI. Maybe some components should be *singletons* during a single request, and each request should work with its own *singleton*. Same component used in another environment maybe shouldn't be a *singleton*, but just a transient object (i.e. each time you inject it, it's a completely new object). With common singleton implementations you won't get this flexibility.

### Your requirement done right

There're many possible approaches to provide a good solution to your problem. I'll describe two of many possible solutions:

#### 1. Instead of thinking about a *global settings* object, you should inject these settings as a class of settings into each component where you require these settings

For example:

```
public interface IDatabaseSettings 
{
     string Host { get; set; }
}

public class RegistryDatabaseSettings : IDatabaseSettings
{
     // This property should get and set the setting from and
     // against the Windows Registry. It's just a sample and dummy
     // implementation
     public string Host { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeRepository
{
}

public class SomeRepositoryImpl : ISomeRepository
{
    private readonly IDatabaseSettings _dbSettings;

    // Inject IDatabaseSetttings as constructor's dependency
    public SomeRepositoryImpl(IDatabaseSettings dbSettings)
    {
         _dbSettings = dbSettings;
    }

    public IDatabaseSettings DatabaseSettings => _dbSettings;
}
```

And using your favourite inversion of control/dependency injection container, you can define that `IDatabaseSettings` must be instantiated once per application cycle (i.e. singleton).

#### 2. If settings are a cross-layer concern...

...maybe you can define a class called `Settings` where you define all settings as public properties and you inject a singleton instance into any component requiring it:

```
public interface IDatabaseSettings
{
     string Host { get; set; }
}

public interface ISettings 
{ 
     IDatabaseSettings Database { get; }
}

public interface ISomeRepository
{
}

public class SomeRepositoryImpl : ISomeRepository
{
    private readonly ISettings _settings;

    // Inject Settings as constructor's dependency
    public SomeRepositoryImpl(ISettings settings)
    {
         _settings = settings;

         // Now you can access DatabaseSettings as follows:
         // Settings.Database.Host
    }

    public ISettings Settings => _settings;
}
```

For me, the issue with this approach is you're going to inject settings to components that shouldn't access/write settings which are from other domains or they're just not desirable to be accessed everywhere. I'm talking about not breaking one of most important principles in object-oriented programming: **encapsulation**.

<sup>(1) When I talk about a singleton pattern implementation *as is*, I'm describing a common singleton pattern implementation where the whole singleton class implements the single object life instantiation/management.</sup>

<sup>(2) OP talks about a settings that should be stored in some database and in Windows Registry. It would be a bad idea not using dependency injection, **because there would be no chance to unit test a component requiring the whole settings without also involving the database and Windows Registry. Setting fakes wouldn't be possible.**</sup>

<sup>(3) Some inversion of control containers have support to configure components using custom factories, where you can define that an instance of some implementation can be taken from any custom source. For example, that factory can return `SomeSingleton.Instance` and get it injected as any regular component.</sup>

Comment: I am confused.  Your answer start with a firm (though completely unsupported) assertion that singletons are not acceptable in DDD.  Shortly after you indicate that injecting a singleton is fine.  Seems like a bit of a contradiction.

Comment: @Cerad it's not confusing... One thing is implementing the singleton pattern *as is* and other is delegating object life cycle to some framework so you decide if there's a single instance within the same application or service or each time you inject some component will be a different instance

Comment: @Cerad I've edited my answer to be more concise, with a sample implementation of singleton pattern.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern "In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object."  What exactly do you mean by "as is"?  Seems like you might be talking about global variables or something but singletons are singletons regardless of how they might be implemented.  I see you added an example of a "simple" implementation but I don't see what that has to do with the question.

Comment: @Cerad You're looking to create a discussion in the wrong way. You know what I mean. If you check the samples of how to implement it on this Wikipedia article you'll find what I mean with "as is"...

Comment: Fair enough.  Given that singletons have nothing to do with DDD then I guess a down vote is in order.

Comment: Still, the very first sentence is just an opinion. Not every object should be swappable, the whole idea of DI is that only parts of your system have to conform to it. A real alternative to a singleton is a factory where both a type and a lifetime policy of created instances can be controlled. The ioc should even not be mentioned here as it is only one of possible ways to implement open factories.

Comment: @Cerad, in your case, I don't care about your downvote. If you feel that my answer requires a downvote, you're free to do it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm not saying that DDD states nothing about singletons. In OP's case, using a common singleton implementation is a bad idea, isn't it?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I've edited again. See the notes at the bottom of the answer body. I provide more background about the topic..

Comment: My point is that you are probably too strict on denying singletons. Instead you could see them as specific way to implement factories, a way that violates the open-closed principle. Whether or not violating rules is "modern" or not though is subjective.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Well, in some scenarios I'm very strict. You're right! :D BTW, even factories can be injected... For example, see the evolution of AutoMapper. Now the mapper is provided as an interface and it can be injected wherever you need it using an IoC container. See the old but yet modern NHibernate, where its session factory is also an interface to let it be injected using DI.

Comment: @WiktorZychla At the end of the day, testability of a given system is one of most important requirements, and unit testing static factories can be very painful, can't be?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I've re-re-re-edited my answer to expand even more my thoughts.

Comment: I am not against your answer, frankly, I was the one to upvote you because of the overall quality of your answer, however I partially understand someone who downvoted the original, unedited version, that possibly sounded too strict.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Maybe maybe... IMHO, in my case I would use my effort providing another answer instead of downvoting some just because it's *too strict*. If I downvote some Q or A, it's because its content is of a very poor quality...

Comment: @WiktorZychla After all, I believe that answering DDD questions is risky because DDD is a development paradigm and how to implement it in code isn't opinionated... Anyway, I feel that pointing out that DDD requires a good separation of concerns and the irrefutable role of inversion of control to aid on this goal has been information both for the OP and also for future readers

Comment: One of possible ways to improve your answer would be not to mention IoC containers at all while emphasizing Dependency Inversion as a general rule. This is because the an container is an implementation detail of the general DI rule, similarily to what Singleton does as a creation pattern. As for possible reasons someone downvoted you, apparently the downvoter hasn't provided their own answer.